Cannot import a wasm node module
I have tried to import a wasm node module from this GitHub link:
(async ()=>global.gp = await require('@sagemath/pari')())(
    
)

but it did not work and I got this error:

TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /Users/ABCDE/node_modules/@sagemath/pari/dist/gp-sta.wasm
Uncaught RuntimeError RuntimeError: abort(TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /Users/ABCDE/node_modules/@sagemath/pari/dist/gp-sta.wasm). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
at abort (file:///Users/ABCDE/node_modules/@sagemath/pari/dist/gp-sta.js:9:10578)
at emit (node:events:520:28)
at emitUnhandledRejection (node:internal/process/promises:250:13)
at throwUnhandledRejectionsMode (node:internal/process/promises:385:19)
at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:470:17)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:32)
Process exited with code 7

Why am I getting this error?
